# Проблема с выводом двух массивов в Matlab

Tags: массивы, matlab

Нужно чтобы 2 массива выводились в таком виде:

```
 string1 double1
 string2 double2
```

и так далее.
При выполнении кода получается следующее:

```
  ID:  NaN
  Eccentricity:   NaN
  Orbital Inclination(rad): NaN
  SQRT(A)  (m 1/2): NaN
  Argument of Perigee(rad) NaN
  Af0(s):  NaN
  week: 1.000000
  0 0.011064
  319488 0.985429
  -7.943188009e-09 5153.630859
  0.8422198678 0.890038
  -1.977771616 0.000566
  -1.091393642e-11 127.000000
```

т.е. сначала идут все переменные из массива строк, а затем все переменные из массива double.
Код:

```
%% Show results
clear;
load ImportResults.mat;
fID3 = fopen('out.txt', 'w');
fprintf(fID3, '          %s %f\r\n', [FieldNames;Variables]);  
fprintf(fID3, '---------------------------------');
```

В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

Функция `fprintf` принимает на вход элементы массива. В `matlab` массив может быть только однотипным типом данных. В вашем же коде массив не является однотипным, он - `string` и `double`. Но вы явно передаете элементы в один массив и `matlab` осуществляет каст к одному типу, преобразуя `Variables` к `string`.

Если хотите иметь массив с разными типами данных, создайте тип `cell`. Пример:

```
Cell_F = {"wow" "Ahah" "Nice"; 1.3 1.4 6.9}
fprintf("%s %f\r\n", Cell_F{:})
```

`Cell_F{:}` создает список массивов, разделенных запятыми, которые содержат данные каждой ячейки `Cell_F`.